# Where should i store the user data to the database or to Redis cache

Tags: reactjs, database, spring-boot, redis

I have a  workflow wizard type of web application (built with ReactJS) with 5 pages, with each page having some input fields and a “Save and Next” button and the final page has “Save and Submit” button.

The logged-in user has an option to logout after any page, he should be able to continue from where he left off when he logs-in back to the application.

My question is where should I save the user entered data on clicking “Save and Next” button on each page, I have an option of storing data to the database or Redis cache.

Comment: if you want the users to continue from where they left on any device, then store to a DB, else if you want the behavior on the same device, you can use localStorage also

Answer (score 0):

You have three possible options for interim storage:

**1. Local In Memory storage.**

**2. Distributed in memory cache ( redis is an example)**

**3. Database.**

For **option 1**, the cost is very cheap and can be retrieved easily. But it depends on the stickiness to the servers to keep ensure it works.

For **option 2**, the cost is higher and the querying capability is limited. But can work in case of a distributed environment but scalable.

For **option 3**, the cost is higher than the above two but the querying capability is also very high. Has the advantage of the above. Many databases like Mongo also support option 2.

As a solution, **i would go with 2, in memory cache** for the use case as the query will always be key based and you can remove the record after a certain period of time.